# Displaying S3 image in image tag?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, amazon-s3

I have uploaded images to S3, now in html I want to simply retrieve them so I did:

```
<a href="{{ url('/') }}">
    <img class="navbar-brand" src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/production/public/images/logo-small.png">
</a>
```

However, image is not displaying, If I put the link in the browser I get:

> public/images/logo-small.png

And not the actual image.

What am I doing wrong here?

Another problem I have is that all my css and js have

`{{ asset('path/to/file') }}` which works fine locally but not on my webserver as it gives me http://domain while my server has https://

Now, If I change asset to secure_asset, it works however then locally it doesn't as my local build is obviously not secured.

How can I solve these two problems?

Comment: Could you specify the laravel version?

Comment: It's laravel 5.4

Comment: If I visit your image url I get *The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.*.

Comment: https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/liveandnow-production/public/images/logo-small.png

Comment: it's because I haven't given a real path, try one above

Answer (score 0):

Okey, first things first, the `public` directory doesn't need to be called, since is the default root of the server, so your url would look like this:

> /images/logo-small.png

The asset() helper function, as the documentation mentions:

> Generate a URL for an asset using the current scheme of the request
>   (HTTP or HTTPS)

So you might need to change your request scheme, check at you `.env` file too, the `APP_URL` field is set using https.

Finally I would recommend you to set the s3 as a storage disk so you can call helpers like this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$url = Storage::url('file.jpg');
```

As additional information, I have had issues with s3 in the past when my files weren't public, so I couldn't access them via url, check in the file configuration in your s3 panel if is set to public, you can check its url at that same panel too.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: my asset looks like this <link href="{{asset ('css/bootstrap.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> and app_url is set to https that is all good however I have 100 images to retrieve and I will be storing a link in a db

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas Check in your s3 admin panel the url the files have and if they are public.

Comment: i am not storing css and js in s3, these are stored locally however the link is http etc while it should be https etc that is the issue with that css

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas are you sure the .env in your server is correct?

Comment: like 150% I am sure, I don't know why it is not working, on my dev server I have exactly same configuration just different url and everything is fine, but on prod it isn't

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas try clearing the cache, I'm afraid I cannot help you with this amount of information

Answer (score 0):

Answer of your second question redirecting with HTTP and HTTPS.

Check your working environment by using `env('APP_ENV')` and put conditions accordingly. To achieve this simply create a middleware and according to environment redirect URL with `HTTPS or HTTP`.

If you are using `Laravel 5+`.

Here is sample of Middleware:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Middleware;

/**
 * Secure
 * Redirects any non-secure requests to their secure counterparts.
 *
 * @param request The request object.
 * @param $next The next closure.
 * @return redirects to the secure counterpart of the requested uri.
*/
class Secure implements Middleware
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $secureEnvs = ['dev', 'qa', 'stage', 'prod'];
        $isSecureEnv = in_array(env('APP_ENV'), $secureEnvs);
        $requestNotSecure = $request->header('x-forwarded-proto') !== 'https';

        // If environment is secure and request is not redirect
        if ($isSecureEnv && $requestNotSecure) {
            return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Add an entry of this middleware in your `$routeMiddleware` array.